# SharePoint Server 2019 - Unable to find 'Save List as Template' option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, 2019

In the **List settings** page, there is no 'Save List as Template' option as per screenshot.
Is there any possible reasons / settings that could be causing this?

[image]

We tried alternatives like directly accessing the `savetmpl.aspx` page, but to no avail. We were getting 'Access Denied' error if we tried to do so (screenshot below)[image]

Is there a specific permission we need for this feature?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have publishing feature enabled?

https://sharepointmaven.com/2-reasons-why-you-cannot-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint/

Comment: @Christoffer No, it is disabled. Any other possible reasons you could think of?